# no puedo enviar una transaccion atravez de ethereumjs-tx

Tags: nodejs, npm

estoy escribiendo un codigo para provar la libreria web3 soy nuevo en esto pero me esta generando un error el codigo es:

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/b076679b90ce4f709b5f6d7b3b51bedf")
const address1 = "0xb034c01065C95B7f7B3b59bed4F16b1Ef426b930"
const address2 = "0x3a3fC3E59029313324c837ADF00e8149399aE0ae"
const addresskey =  new Buffer.from("EE048D4584C4D87FDC0EF40B628F449671432D50C60D801F30D9BC977FA9C1E0", "hex")
web3.eth.getTransaction(address2, (err, txCount) => {
var rawTx = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei("2", "gwei")),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        to: address1,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(5000000000000000000)
      }
      const tx =  new EthereumTx(rawTx, {"chain": "ropsten"})
      tx.sign(addresskey)
      serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString("hex")
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx).on("receipt",console.log)
})
```

pero me lanza un error: nonce too low

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo obtengo previamente, a traves de una consulta asíncrona:

`const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(tu_address);`